# I deployed GWT on tomcat and now RPC does not work

Tags: gwt, tomcat, rpc

I just deployed my GWT project on tomcat. I can open the page. But my RPC doesn't work anymore. I'm getting: rpc.StatusCodeException: 404

Answer (score 2):

There must be a servlet mapping problem. Take look at your web.xml file.